# Converting Path Extension to Lowercase in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to convert a path extension to lowercase in swift. This should be fairly easy, but when I use the obvious code, I keep getting an error:

```
var filePath = "/path/to/file.CSV"
var fileExtension = filePath.pathExtension
fileExtension.lowercaseString //ERROR happens when I try to convert to lowercase
```

error is the following:

> execution failed: error: Execution was interrupted, reason:
>   EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0).
>       The process has been left at the point where it was interrupted, use "thread return -x" to return to the state before expression
>   evaluation.
>       * thread #1: tid = 0x231209, 0x00000001083083a6, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1,
>   address=0x0)
>         * frame #0: 0x00000001083083a6

When I convert any other string to lowercase, it's completely fine.

My workaround has been to just convert the filePath to lowercase before getting the extension, but I just wanted to know if anyone else is having this issue?

Comment: I am going to go with "bug".  This works - `
fileExtension.lowercaseStringWithLocale(NSLocale(localeIdentifier:"en"))`

Comment: Replace your second line to: `var fileExtension: NSString = filePath.pathExtension`

Comment: It looks like this bug has been corrected in the meantime (XCode 6.1)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a bug for me as well, one work around is to cast the String to `NSString` like:

```
var filePath = "/path/to/file.CSV"
var fileExtension = filePath.pathExtension
(fileExtension as NSString).lowercaseString
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it on this way too:

```
var filePath = "/path/to/file.CSV"
((filePath as NSString).pathExtension).lowercaseString
```